# how can we achieve biometric login using google smart lock?

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

Suppose I am enrolled with fingerprint in device so can we save something to google smart lock like adaptive token and next time when user reinstall the app and try to login app we can fetch adaptive token and do login using fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use biometric verification to install anything on the device. You can use it only to verify that the person is authorization to use the device (or at least can unlock it). You need to kind of login binding to do that e.g. Firebase Auth, there you can store everything you need to restore your app state.